# Focusing the empty entry box when user clicks the error messagebox in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In tkinter GUI, i have created a "signup to an account" window. If the user clicks the sign-up button with one or more entries (in entry boxes) unfilled, a error message box appears.
The thing I want is that when the user clicks the "OK" button of tkinter error messagebox, the cursor should be moved to that particular empty entry box, hence indicating the user which entry box is empty.

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

class MyGUI:
def __init__(self):
    self.root = Tk()

    self.entrybox = []

    for i in range(9): #Creating 9 Entry Boxes
        self.entrybox.append(Entry(self.root, width = 10, font = 'Verdana 10'))

    for i in self.entrybox: #packing each Entry Box      
        i.pack(pady = 5)

    okButton = Button(self.root, text = 'OK', command = self.get_entryvalues)
    okButton.pack()

    mainloop()

def get_entryvalues(self):
    values = []
    for i in self.entrybox:
        values.append(i.get())
    if '' in values:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Error', '1 or more entries are not filled!', parent = self.root)
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Info', 'Form submitted', parent = self.root)


mygui = MyGUI()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have not included any code, here is a snippet to help you through.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()


def something():
    if e.get() == '':
        messagebox.showerror('Error message box',
                             'Please fill the blank field', parent=root)
        e.focus_force() #to get the lost focus back


l = Label(root, text='Snippet')
l.pack()

e = Entry(root)
e.pack(pady=10)

b = Button(root, text='Click me!!', command=something)
b.pack()

e.focus_force()  # to have focus to the entry box wen the program starts

root.mainloop()
```

Here if you your entry field is blank it gives a messagebox and after you click on ok the focus goes back to the entry box of the window.

The `parent` argument in `messagebox` is totally optional if you have just 1 window, but it gives some focus to the window that the messagebox appears over (if you're working over with more than 1 window.

Let me know if anything is wrong or if you have doubts :D

Comment: Now here in my code, i have created 9 entry boxes using for loop.Suppose user fills only the 3rd and 5th box.  Now when the user will click 'OK' button, error message box will appear. Now I want the cursor to move to the 1st empty box. When it is filled, move the cursor to the  2nd empty box, then to the 4th empty box, then to the 6th and so on. The code you had attached is understood for 1 entry box. But in my case, now i have 9 entry boxes and i don't know which box or boxes will be remained unfilled by the user.

Comment: i personally dont think it is a practical way to use loop to create entry boxes, cuz if the person has more than 2 empty boxes the cursor would go wer? and then u have to mark up each empty entry box? code gets trickier there, so its recomended to use variables and make individual entry boxes so u have more flexibility with the values and  all. Im still looking for a way

Comment: But don't you think it will be difficult and will make the code long if we create entry boxes separately. I mean suppose I have 20 entry boxes instead of 9. Now i will have to make 20 individual boxes, pack them, then get their values individually by assigning 20 different variables. And in that case also, how the problem of the cursor will be solved?

Comment: i think acw1668 already gave u the answer you want ?

Comment: Yes, i got my answer. Thank you both of you!! 

Answer (score 2):

You can just call `focus()` on the first empty entry found in the for loop inside `get_entryvalues()` function:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()

        self.entrybox = []
        for i in range(9): #Creating 9 Entry Boxes
            btn = Entry(self.root, width=10, font='Verdana 10')
            btn.pack(pady=5)
            btn.bind('<Return>', self.next_entry)
            self.entrybox.append(btn)

        okButton = Button(self.root, text='OK', command=self.get_entryvalues)
        okButton.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def get_entryvalues(self):
        for e in self.entrybox:
            if e.get().strip() == '':
                tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Error', '1 or more entries are not filled!', parent=self.root)
                e.focus() # focus the empty entry
                return
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Info', 'Form submitted', parent=self.root)

    def next_entry(self, event):
        event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()

mygui = MyGUI()
```

Comment: Yes, it's working. But i want one more thing. Is it possible that when user fills the first entry box and press "Enter Key", then cursor should automatically move to the second entry box. Now what actually is happening is when i have filled an entry box, i have to click on the next entry box to move cursor there, which is quite irritating and less efficient.

Comment: @AdnanAkram Answer updated.  Actually you can press `Tab` key to advance to next entry.